# Reactjs web app - MutationObserver use in Safari browser not as expected

Tags: reactjs, safari, mutation-observers

I have a react webapp that renders 2 text areas which are resize-vertical (using CSS). My requirement is that when one text area is resized by the user, the code captures it and apply the height to the other text area.

Based on my research, currently, there isn't a convenient method like `textarea.onResize()`. So, I am using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver). The API is very elegant and exactly what I need. I was able to configure it properly, capture the change in `style` attribute and apply it to other text area. This works fine in **Google Chrome** (Version 76.0.3809.132 (Official Build) (64-bit)) and **Mozilla FireFox** (Version 68.0.1esr (64-bit)). All this testing was done on Mac OS High Sierra (Version 10.13.6).

### The problem

Although, when it comes to **Safari browser** (Version 12.1.2 (13607.3.10)), it doesn't seem to work as expected.

Upon debugging, I found out that when user resize a given text area, `style` attribute gets appended to it, with some assigned height and for each change, `MutationObserver` observes the change produces a `MutationRecord`, which I capture in my callback to take appropriate actions (in this case, apply height to other text area). Although, **Safari browser does not produce `MutationRecord` for change in `style` attribute when text area is resized by the user.**

Two things:

1. If I inspect the text area in developer mode of the browser and make a change to the `style` attribute of the element, `MutationRecord` is produced correctly and my callback does indeed execute, which is very weird.
2. I created [an example in JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qjkvoLna/1/), where, **in Safari** if you resize the text area, no `MutationRecord` is produced and you won't see any alerts but if you inspect and make a change manually, you will see the alert (appropriate `MutationRecord`s are produced). In **Chrome** or **Firefox**, resizing the text area will produce the window alert without needing to make changes by inspecting the element.

### Code

#### CSS

```
.textField textarea {
    resize: vertical;
}
```

#### componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
 if ('MutationObserver' in window) {
      const config =  {
        attributes: true,
        subtree: true,
        attributeFilter: ['style'],
        attributeOldValue: true
      };

      const sourceTextArea = window.getElementById('sourceTextArea');
      this.sourceObserver =  new MutationObserver(this.handleManualSourceTextAreaResize);
      this.sourceObserver.observe(sourceTextArea, config);

      const targetTextArea = window.getElementById('targetTextArea');
      this.targetObserver =  new MutationObserver(this.handleManualTargetTextAreaResize);
      this.targetObserver.observe(targetTextArea, config);
    }
}
```

#### Callback for source text area

```
handleManualSourceTextAreaResize = (mutationsList, observer) => {
    const sourceTextArea = getElement('sourceTextArea');
    const targetTextArea = getElement('targetTextArea').children[0];

    if (!this.isStopPropagation) {
      targetTextArea.setAttribute('style',  'height: ' + sourceTextArea.offsetHeight + 'px');
      this.isStopPropagation = true;
    } else {
      this.isStopPropagation = false;
    }
  }
```

#### Callback for target text area

```
  handleManualTargetTextAreaResize = (mutationsList, observer) => {
    const sourceTextArea = getElement('sourceTextArea').children[0];
    const targetTextArea = getElement('targetTextArea');

    if (!this.isStopPropagation) {
      sourceTextArea.setAttribute('style',  'height: ' + targetTextArea.offsetHeight + 'px'');
      this.isStopPropagation = true;
    } else {
      this.isStopPropagation = false;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Safari. You'll have to poll clientHeight periodically in setTimeout/setInterval, I'm afraid. Or if you're lucky maybe someone has a better solution. BTW in new Chrome/FF you can use ResizeObserver API

Comment: I did file a bug with Safari, but as expected, I was unsuccessful in getting any attention. And yes, I came across the `ResizeObserver`, but the `MutationObserver` works fine for Chrome and Firefox anyway, so I'm good there. The problem is specifically for Safari browser.

Comment: Safari 13 (Technology Preview) supports ResizeObserver.

Comment: You'll need to use ```WebKitMutationObserver``` for ios. so in my case i have this conditional:
//
```var observer = new MutationObserver(loopCheckSelector);//
    if (!observer){\
      observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(loopCheckSelector);\
    }
    observer.observe(container, vg_observerOptions);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `WebKitMutationObserver` for ios. so in my case i have this conditional:

```
var observer = new MutationObserver(loopCheckSelector);
if (!observer){
  observer = new WebKitMutationObserver(loopCheckSelector);
}
observer.observe(container, observerOptions);
```

You can also switch the conditions if your traffic is primarily ios for example.